# Cannot reset mysql password as root

Tags: mysql, passwords

i am using CentOs with mysql 5 version, forgot my password, and i cannot reset it, what i did is

```
/etc/init.d/mysqld stop

mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &
mysql -u root

mysql>  update mysql.user set password=PASSWORD("pass") where User='root';
```

got this message

```
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 0  Changed: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> flush privileges; exit;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

Stopped and strated mysql but its anyway

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

i have tried this solution [mysql official site](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/resetting-permissions.html), not working anyway. Any suggestions?

## UPDATE

**My main user was `admin` not `root` so i changed password for admin all is ok now, sorry for this. thanks everyone.**

Comment: i resolved my problem, read update, please close this. thank you everyone.

Comment: Nice you found it, close the question then.

Answer (score 2):

Have a closer look at your error message:

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
                                                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

You might have set a new password, but you are not using it to connect.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me

```
   UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('foobar') WHERE User='tom' AND Host='localhost';
```

This did not work for me

```
   SET PASSWORD FOR 'user-name-here'@'hostname-name-here' = PASSWORD('new-password-here');
```

Comment: Just FLUSH PRIVILEGES afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

```
Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'  (using password: NO)
```

make sure what ever is trying to login is definatly sending a password

Answer (score -1):

Try to flush privalages after resetting the password:

```
    UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('MyNewPass') WHERE User='root';
    FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

If that doesn't work follow these steps: [How to Reset the Root Password](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/resetting-permissions.html)

Comment: Please re-read the question carefully. He already does what you suggest and he already links what you link.