# Can not set a Password for MySQL

Tags: mysql, lamp

i have logged-in to MySQL (-v 5.7.22) using shell as **root**. but when i try to set a password for it using this command:
`UPDATE mysql.user SET Password = PASSWORD('Mypass') WHERE User = 'root';`
i get this error:
`ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'Password' in 'field list'`
any way to set a password for it and use it **without** becoming root( like connecting PhpStorm to it)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot reset mysql password as root](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13916532/cannot-reset-mysql-password-as-root)

Comment: It would be helpful if you mention MySQL version you are using. There are some changes in user management in latest versions.

Comment: Do not update the table manually, instead use the [statements designed for this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/set-password.html): `SET PASSWORD FOR 'jeffrey'@'localhost' = 'auth_string';`

Comment: @Matt Clark - i used that one too, but nothing changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `UPDATE mysql.user SET Password = PASSWORD('Mypass') WHERE User = 'root';`
Replace **Password** with **authentication_string** and see the magic.

Answer (score -1):

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET Password = 'Mypass' WHERE 
User = 'root';
```

Comment: And this is different from the query in the original question how?